# Why does this not compare the characters?

Tags: c, cs50

```
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    int main(int argc, string argv[])
    {
    
        int x = 0;
        string alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        int key_length = strlen(argv[1]);
    
        //checks if key is valid
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (key_length < 26)
        {
            printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    
        //takes input from user
        string plaintext = ("Hello");
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //loops until characters are the same
            while (strcmp(plaintext[i], alphabet[x]) != 0)
            {
                x++;
            }
            //prints character
            printf("%s", argv[1][x]);
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
substitution.c:30:23: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
        while (strcmp(plaintext[i], alphabet[x]) != 0)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                      &
/usr/include/string.h:156:32: note: passing argument to parameter '__s1' here
extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
                               ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: substitution] Error 1
```

Comment: Unless you're doing this for a course that strictly requires `cs50.h`, please don't use that. It promotes a lot of bad practices. `string` isn't a thing in C as it is in C++, and the function signatures you're going to see in the documentation won't use that term.

Comment: @tadman can you elaborate? why `cs50.h` is bad?

Comment: @CIsForCookies A) It invents its own pseudo-dialect for C which has no connection, at all, to what real-world C code looks like. B) The documentation does not use their conventions, making for a serious disconnect when trying to resolve issues exactly like this. C) It doesn't do anything even remotely beneficial, it only serves to obfuscate.

Comment: @CIsForCookies In other words, "Leave C alone!" Learn C without the silly training wheels and you'll be a lot more comfortable operating in real code-bases solving real problems.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` compares two character strings. To compare two characters, `==` can be used.

Remember: `char* x = "..."` defines a character array, `x[n]` is a character, and to C characters are just numbers, ergo `plaintext[i] == alphabet[x]` is valid.

You may want to use [`strchr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) here to optimize this as there's no need to bash through byte by byte.

```c
strchr(alphabet, plaintext[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

The error `incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'` comes because you run `strcmp` not on a `string` (`const char *`) but on a `string[index]` (`char`).

You should either `strcmp(string1, string2)` [compare strings] or check `string1[index] == string2[index]` [compare `char`]